# Как в шаблон вставить php-файл?

Tags: php, html

Используется простой шаблонизатор по типу:

```
$output = str_replace ("{TITLE}", $title, $template);
echo $output;
```

Как в шаблон вставить php-файл?

Comment: использовать шаблонизатор посложнее

Comment: проблема в том, что вы судя по всему с шаблоном взаимодействуете как со строкой. Чтобы внедрить туда код, надо будет его потом не просто вывести, а выполнить. Либо выполнить, а результат вставить, что в данном случае будет проще и целесообразнее

Comment: Переписать скрипт на шаблонизатор посложнее планирую попозже. Все упирается во время. Вопрос - как выполнить php скрипт и записать его результат в текст?

Comment: Вы работаете с шаблоном как со строкой, видимо в самом шаблоне у Вас есть php код и соответственно он не выполняется (чтобы в страницу вставить шаблон его нужно выполнить)

Comment: Шаблонизаторы обычно химичат с ob_start(); echo '....'; $out = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); чтобы выполнить код но записать в переменную

Comment: "Вопрос - как выполнить php скрипт и записать его результат в текст?" вы задали этот вопрос в пространство час назад. Если бы вы вписали его не в поле для комментария, а в адресную строку своего браузера, ваш костыль уже бы работал.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже в комментах отмечено про буферизацию вывода, можете пойти примерно таким путем:

Включаемый файл (`tpl.php`) будет иметь примерно следующий вид

```
<?php    
    ob_start();

    echo "какой-то текст";   // тут весь выполняемый код и т.п.

    $result = ob_get_contents();    
    ob_clean();

    return $result;
```

начали буферизацию, выполнили код/хтмл и т.п. затем, все что в буфере вытолкнули в переменную, и буфер очистили. Переменную вернули из скрипта.

А вот вы в вызывающем файле как-то так

```
$tpl = include "./tpl.php";       // инклуд файла с резалтом в переменную

$output = str_replace ("{TITLE}", $title, $template);
$output = str_replace("{TPL}", $tpl, $output);  // и замена, как раньше.
echo $output;
```

Можете хоть регулярками реплейсить с колбеком

```
$template = <<<TPL
<body>
    {INC "tpl.php"}
    <br/>
    {INC "tpl.php"}
TPL;

echo "123";

$out = preg_replace_callback('/\{INC\s+"(?<file>.*?)"\}/', function($v){
                return include "./" . $v['file'];
            }, $template);

echo $out;
```